# What are the differences between "each", "foreach", "collect" and "map"?

Tags: ruby, loops, enums, iterator, iteration

It seems like there are a lot of ways to loop over an Enumerable in Ruby. Are there any differences between `each`, `foreach`, or in `collect`, `map` or other similar methods?

Or is there a reason I shouldn't use certain methods in certain situations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`collect`/`map` are equivalent. They differ from `each` in that `each` only executes the block for each element, whereas `collect`/`map` return an array with the results of calling the block for each element. Another way to put it might be, `each` is expected to *do* something with each element, whereas `map` is expected to *transform* each element (map it onto something else).

You could use `collect` or `map` anywhere `each` is used, and your code will still work. But it will probably be slightly less efficient because it collects the results in an array, unless your Ruby implementation realizes it doesn't have to bother creating an array because it's never used.

Another reason to use `each` instead of `map` or `collect` is to help out anyone reading your code. If I see `each` then I can be like okay, we're about to use each element of the data to do something. If I see `map` then I'm expecting to see new data being created, based on a remapping of the old data.

With regards to `map` vs. `collect` I would say it's a matter of preference, but you should pick one and stick with it for consistency.

Comment: "`each` is expected to do something with each element, whereas `map` is expected to transform each element" Isn't transforming also a form of doing? The difference is not in what to do, but in what to return.

Answer (score 1):

`Array#collect` (and `Array#map`) return a new array based on the code passed in the block.  `Array#each` performs an operation (defined by the block) on each element of the array.

I would use `collect` like this:

```
array = [1, 2, 3]
array2 = array.collect {|val| val + 1}

array.inspect # => "[1, 2, 3]"
array2.inspect # => "[2, 3, 4]"
```

And `each` like this:

```
array = [1, 2, 3]
array.each {|val| puts val + 1 }
# >> 2
# >> 3
# >> 4
array.inspect # => "[1, 2, 3]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `pry` and `Rubinus` (it's easier to read ruby code) take a look for yourself

```
$ pry
[1] pry(main)> cd Enumerable
[2] pry(Enumerable):1> show-method collect

From: .../rbx-head/kernel/common/enumerable18.rb @ line 4:
Owner: Enumerable
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 9

def collect
  if block_given?
    ary = []
    each { |o| ary << yield(o) }
    ary
  else
    to_a
  end
end

[3] pry(Enumerable):1> show-method map

From: .../rbx-head/kernel/common/enumerable18.rb @ line 4:
Owner: Enumerable
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 9

def collect
  if block_given?
    ary = []
    each { |o| ary << yield(o) }
    ary
  else
    to_a
  end
end
[4] pry(Enumerable):1>
```

So  nope not for these two.

`map` and `collect` iterate over a collection. For each object it executes your block then collects the result. The `each` methods do not collect the results